# Databricks Notebook: Call pyspark function parallelly

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, python-multithreading

I am trying to call pyspark function parallelly, these functions are loading multiple databricks tables to Azure SQL-

```
def __exportToSql(dbtable, sqltable):
    try:
        print("{0}, start time :{1}".format(dbtable, str(datetime.datetime.now())))
        _df = spark.table(dbtable)
        display(_df)
        _df.write.format("jdbc") \
            .mode("overwrite") \
            .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
            .option("dbtable", sqltable) \
            .option("user", jdbcUsername) \
            .option("password", jdbcPassword) \
            .save()
        
        print("{0}, export completed  :{1}".format(dbtable, str(datetime.datetime.now())))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    p1 = Process(target=__exportToSql, args=('dbtable1', 'sqltable1'))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=__exportToSql, args=('dbtable2', 'sqltable2'))
    p2.start()
    p3 = Process(target=__exportToSql, args=('dbtable3', 'sqltable3'))
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

if I call this function individually, export is working fine but on execution of above code I am getting below exception -

*

> Unable to parse datatype from schema. 'bool' object has no attribute
> 'schema' 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode' Unable to parse
> datatype from schema. 'bool' object has no attribute 'schema'*

Since these export are not dependent on each other, we can call them parallelly. How I can run above code parallelly without any error?

Answer (score 0):

- "**Unable to parse datatype from schema. 'bool' object has no attribute 'schema**'",  Error states that there might be an issue
  with the data or the schema you are trying to export.
- It seems that one of the tables (dbtable1, dbtable2, or dbtable3) has a column with a boolean datatype, which is causing an error during the export process.
- To resolve this issue, you should investigate the schema of the tables and ensure that the datatypes of all columns are compatible with the target SQL tables.

I have tried using the same BOOLEAN datatype and tried to export tables to Azure SQL.

**Below is the code:**

```
def exportToSql(dbtable, sqltable):
try:
print(f"{dbtable}, start time: {datetime.datetime.now()}")
df = spark.table(dbtable)
if df.count() > 0:
df.show(5)
df.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", jdbcUrl) \
.option("dbtable", sqltable) \
.options(**connectionProperties) \
.mode("overwrite") \
.save()
print(f"{dbtable}, export completed: {datetime.datetime.now()}")
else:
print(f"{dbtable} is empty. Skipped export.")
except Exception as ex:
print(ex)
if  __name__ == '__main__':
p1 = Process(target=exportToSql, args=('people', 'dbtable1'))
p1.start()
p1.join()  
p2 = Process(target=exportToSql, args=('contacts', 'dbtable2'))
p2.start()
p2.join()
p3 = Process(target=exportToSql, args=('locations', 'dbtable3'))
p3.start()
p3.join()
```

[image]

[image]

**Tables Exported to Azure SQL:**
[image]